# UIPrintInteractionController throws UICollectionViewFlowLayout errors on iPhone 6Plus, 6SPlus and iPad Air 2

Tags: objective-c, printing, uicollectionview, uiprintinteractioncntrler

I have an iOS app (Base SDK 8.0) that allows the user to print some text.

The app works fine on all devices on the iOS 8.4 simulator, and everything apart from iPhone 6Plus, 6S Plus, and iPad Air 2 on the 9.3 simulator.

For those devices on 9.3 everything still prints okay, but it throws the following warnings:

> 2016-06-28 12:29:11.380 AppName[46451:4620456] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for .
>   2016-06-28 12:29:11.437 AppName[46451:4620456] the behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
>   2016-06-28 12:29:11.437 AppName[46451:4620456] the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.
>   2016-06-28 12:29:11.437 AppName[46451:4620456] The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is , and it is attached to ; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {1074, 382.66666666666663}> collection view layout: .
>   2016-06-28 12:29:11.438 AppName[46451:4620456] Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.
>   2016-06-28 12:29:11.446 AppName[46451:4620456] the behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
>   2016-06-28 12:29:11.446 AppName[46451:4620456] the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.
>   2016-06-28 12:29:11.447 AppName[46451:4620456] The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is , and it is attached to ; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {1074, 382.66666666666663}> collection view layout: .
>   2016-06-28 12:29:11.447 AppName[46451:4620456] Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.

I realise there are two errors shown here:

1. unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions
2. UICollectionViewFlowLayout errors

However, from Googling they seem to be part and parcel of the same error: something to do with the print preview pane in iOS 9.x.

Has anyone seen this problem before, and have a solution?

Thanks

Darren.

Comment: Looks like this is a bug in either iOS or Xcode. I've been asked to raise it as a bug with Apple.

Comment: Did you get a response from Apple, or can you post a link to the Radar?